# how to install apache benchmark on mac

Tags: macos, apache, apachebench

I am trying to install Apache BenchMark on my macos(macOS Mojave) through brew using the command :

```
brew install homebrew/apache/ab
```

Getting this error:

```
Error: homebrew/apache was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.
```

Answer (score 95):

**Note! ApacheBench (ab) is installed on macOS by default.**

- You can check that by using

`ab -h [for help/information]`
[for checking ab version]
`ab -V`

> Ref: https://vyspiansky.github.io/2019/12/02/apache-bench-for-load-testing/

Comment: Not in Catalina it's not.

Comment: @ChrisF No, It's still available in macOS Catalina. I verified it on my machine. (Version 10.15.7)

Comment: Ok, but how do I update its version?